# don't want to refresh page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have A HTML table having input field inside which is `autocomplete=on` to store the data,what i am doing is i have one drop-down inside the form and having buttons according to requirement.When user clicks on any drop-down table populates according to it and user enter some inputs to the input field

i have provided a `View` button when user clicks then it shows what user has entered into input fields (all non-zero rows gets populated),on click of view i am hiding view button and showing `edit` button so that user again can edit after viewing the data

when user clicks on `edit` i am calling `addTable(tableData)` my table function and again displaying the table,but on clicking on edit it shows up the Table but all input fields resets to `0` which not the expected behavior of code,as i am using `autocomplete=on` it should store the values into the input field until user refresh the page
I am using `autocomplete=on` for that,but still it gets refresh

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1978",
    "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },

  {
    "Item Code": "1981",
    "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1982",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1984",
    "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1985",
    "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1986",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1987",
    "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1989",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1990",
    "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1992",
    "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1994",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2402",
    "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "333",
    "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  }
]

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed

  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row.
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }

  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  $("#view").on("click", function() {
    var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");
    if (quantityField === 0) {
      tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata.hide();;

    }
  });
}

addTable(tableData);
var selectedOption = "";
$("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
  selectedOption = this.value;

  //getting all item rows so i can target them.
  var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

  if (selectedOption === "All") {
    //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
    // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";

    }
    /* alert(itemRows); */
    // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
    var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
      selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }

});

function view() {
  //getting all quantity input fields
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  //iterating through all quantity input fields
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is not equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to visible
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {

      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //change the value of the select menu to "All"
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#see').hide();
  $('#edit').show();


}

function edit1(event) { //this is what i am trying
  event.preventDefault();
  addTable(tableData);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>regular</option>
          <option>fastfood</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
      Save
    </button>
      <button id="see" type="button" onclick="view()">view</button>
      <button id="edit" type="button" onclick="edit1(event)" style="display:none">edit</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am trying `event.preventDefault();`but not working

UPDATE: I've added the `event` to the onclick of the edit button.

Comment: I think it should be `onclick="edit1(event)"`

Comment: @CarlBinalla no still it refres the page and my input field goes to 0

Comment: You're right @Carl Binalla. That's what I answered and got a downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54414875/7630248

Comment: @ChrisTapay i haven't down-voted you buddy

Comment: Normally, that would be correct, and you shouldn't even need `preventDefault()` since the button is of `type=button`, they don't submit a form. One more thing, we can't even try the edit button because it has a display of none

Comment: @CarlBinalla, according to logic, the view button shows the edit one.

Comment: @CarlBinalla on click of view the `edit` button is visible you can check

Comment: @viveksingh, it is unclear to me what are you trying to achieve. Could you please edit your post and tell what is the expected behavior? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisTapay  hey i have updated the post ,please help

Comment: `autocomplete=on` does not do what you think it does. Check the documentation out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing to pass the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) from the HTML.

```
<button id="edit" type="button" onclick="edit1(event)" style="display:none">edit</button>
```

Comment: Just renamed the passed event name to `event`. It should work now.

Comment: hey i am doing like this  `function edit1(event) { //this is what i am trying
     event.preventDefault();
     addTable(tableData);
     return false;
 }`  and passing event inside onclik function as you have posted..but still it is refreshing and setting all data to 0,you can check once by running my code snippet

Comment: same problem sir on click of edit the data is getting refreshed and shows up zero in input field ,as i am using `autocomplete=on`, i don't know what is going wrong :(

Comment: Oh, I think I got you: you're trying to keep the edited values, however, you're not updating the data source, you're just loading it all again by calling: `addTable(tableData);` in the `edit1` function. You need to provide a two-way binding mechanism to keep both the view and the data source updated.

Comment: i am not making call to server again and again, i am using css to update my table,if you got my problemplease help me out

Comment: `autocomplete=on` does not do what you think it does. Check the documentation out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete